# Splitting a single string of hashes into an array of hashes

Tags: ruby, regex, hash

I can't get regex to split the string to give the desired result.
http://rubular.com/r/ytFwP3ivAv - according to rubular this expression should work.

```
str = "{"DATE"=>"11/26/2013 11:15", "DESC"=>"Accident (minor)", "LOCATION"=>"12 S THORNTON AV", "DISTRICT"=>"C5", "INCIDENT"=>"2013-00496193"}, {"DATE"=>"11/26/2013 11:10", "DESC"=>"Hold-up alarm", "LOCATION"=>"4725 S KIRKMAN RD", "DISTRICT"=>"E5", "INCIDENT"=>"2013-00496235"}"

sub_str_array = str.split(/({"[\w"=>\/ :,()-]*})/)

# the desired result - each hash is an element in an array
puts the_split[0] #=> {"DATE"=>"11/26/2013 11:15", "DESC"=>"Accident (minor)", "LOCATION"=>"12 S THORNTON AV", "DISTRICT"=>"C5", "INCIDENT"=>"2013-00496193"}
```

Is there another way (an easier way) to convert these string hashes into an array of hashes?

Comment: `str` is not String object. It's Hash object.

Comment: @falsetru, I changed it to a String object. Thanks.

Comment: `str` is an invalid String definition. Try it in IRB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
require 'json'

yourstr = '[' + '{"DATE"=>"11/26/2013 11:15", "DESC"=>"Accident (minor)", "LOCATION"=>"12 S THORNTON AV", "DISTRICT"=>"C5", "INCIDENT"=>"2013-00496193"}, {"DATE"=>"11/26/2013 11:10", "DESC"=>"Hold-up alarm", "LOCATION"=>"4725 S KIRKMAN RD", "DISTRICT"=>"E5", "INCIDENT"=>"2013-00496235"}, {"DATE"=>"11/26/2013 11:08", "DESC"=>"Missing person - adult", "LOCATION"=>"4818 S SEMORAN BV 503", "DISTRICT"=>"K1", "INCIDENT"=>"2013-00496198"}, {"DATE"=>"11/26/2013 11:07", "DESC"=>"911 hang up", "LOCATION"=>"311 W PRINCETON ST", "DISTRICT"=>"C2", "INCIDENT"=>"2013-00496231"}' + ']'

my_hash = JSON.parse(yourstr.gsub("=>", ":"))

puts my_hash[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You've set `str` as an object. Wrap it in quotes and it should work.

It may be better to use `%Q(string goes here)` rather than double quotes.

Comment: It's a String object now. However, the regular expression fails to capture each hash -- please see rubular link above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval "[#{str}]"`, if *str* is hardcoded and nobody can change it.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not hard-coded. It is output from a file that needs to be transformed.

Comment: Do you want split that string in an array of strings or  array of hashes? in second case you must iterate each array element. Eval can be dangerous but depends who is generating that file.